# Largest term in determinant of Banded matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, tridiagonal-matrices

I am looking to find the largest term in determinant of Banded matrix, to approximate determinant with it?  or is there another approach? Specifically i wants know approximately the determinant of following matrices(If dimension of matrix go to infinity):

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
 0 & \text{a0} & \text{b0} & \text{c0} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{c1} & \text{b1} & \text{a1} \\
 \text{a1} & 0 & \text{a0} & \text{b0} & \text{c0} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{c1} & \text{b1} \\
 \text{b1} & \text{a1} & 0 & \text{a0} & \text{b0} & \text{c0} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{c1} \\
 \text{c1} & \text{b1} & \text{a1} & 0 & \text{a0} & \text{b0} & \text{c0} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \text{c1} & \text{b1} & \text{a1} & 0 & \text{a0} & \text{b0} & \text{c0} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \text{c1} & \text{b1} & \text{a1} & 0 & \text{a0} & \text{b0} & \text{c0} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{c1} & \text{b1} & \text{a1} & 0 & \text{a0} & \text{b0} & \text{c0} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{c1} & \text{b1} & \text{a1} & 0 & \text{a0} & \text{b0} & \text{c0} \\
 \text{c0} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{c1} & \text{b1} & \text{a1} & 0 & \text{a0} & \text{b0} \\
 \text{b0} & \text{c0} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{c1} & \text{b1} & \text{a1} & 0 & \text{a0} \\
 \text{a0} & \text{b0} & \text{c0} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{c1} & \text{b1} & \text{a1} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: You can find an exact expression for the determinant of your matrix here, in the Properties section. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix

Comment: Yes, i think it's a way to answer this question but is not so complete. because finally we find a integration over frequency , which again  need to be approximate :$\log \det |A|\propto\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} d\omega \log(|c0+\sum_j c_j\exp[2\pi i\omega]^{n-j}|)$ with definition  given by previous comment link.